# Why does grep treat '[D]ebug' string differently?

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, wildcards

I've created simple text file named "T" to test the unusual behavior of `grep`:

```
    1 Debug
    2 debug
    3 determined
    4 Determined
```

Tried different syntax:

```
    $ grep De T
        1 Debug
        4 Determined
    $ grep de T
        2 debug
        3 determined
    $ grep Determined T
        4 Determined
    $ grep determined T
        3 determined
    $ grep Debug T
        1 Debug
    $ grep debug T
        2 debug
    $ grep [D]ebug T          # Why result is 2-nd line???
        2 debug
    $ grep [Dd]ebug T         # Why result is only one 2-nd line???
        2 debug
    $ grep [Dd]e T
        1 Debug
        2 debug
        3 determined
        4 Determined
    $ grep [d]e T
        2 debug
        3 determined
    $ grep [d]ebug T
        2 debug
    $ grep "[D]ebug" T
        1 Debug
    $ grep "[Dd]ebug" T
        1 Debug
        2 debug
    $ grep [\D]ebug T         # Why result is 2-nd line???
        2 debug
    $ grep --version
        grep (GNU grep) 2.16
```

As you can see, almost every grep call returns correct result, but `$ grep [D]ebug T`, `$ grep [Dd]ebug T`, `$ grep [\D]ebug T` return wrong results. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you should use `grep [D,d]` to grep for both cases of `d`. (Or use grep's case-insensitive option.)

Comment: @Wolfer, I think that you are wrong:
I added `5 ,ebug` line into `T` and `grep [D,d] T` included `5 ,ebug` into output. It treated ',' as an additional substitute character - like 'D' and 'd'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that you probably have a file or directory called `debug` in your current working directory:

```
 $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--   1 jay   wheel   58 Feb  1 05:01 T
 $ grep [D]ebug T
    1 Debug
 $ grep [Dd]ebug T
    1 Debug
    2 debug

 $ touch debug
 $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jay  wheel  58 Feb  1 05:01 T
-rw-r--r--  1 jay  wheel   0 Feb  1 05:05 debug

 $ grep [D]ebug T
    2 debug
 $ grep [Dd]ebug T
    2 debug
```

I commend you on this excellent illustration why you must always escape shell metacharacters.

*Update to clarify what's going on*: I'm assuming you, like I, are using an OS with a case-insensitive filesystem (e.g. a Mac). When you execute the command, your shell performs a number of expansions on it before actually executing `grep`. One of those is [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) in which square brackets provide alternations:

`[Dd]ebug` on a case-**sensitive** filesystem would expand to either `Debug debug`, `Debug` or `debug` depending on what files it could match. Since it only matched the file `debug`, your command became:

```
grep debug T
```

If you remove that file and do `touch Debug`, you'll see the output of your command change because it will be interpolated as

```
grep Debug T
```

Without the `debug` file in your directory, your shell tries to interpolate the brackets but fails without a match so it happens to pass the argument through unchanged.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks.
I'm not really familiar with grep, just an amateur :)

Comment: But I still don't understand what is going on here.
What is exactly the reason for grep to return `2 debug`?

Comment: @user1673789 Maybe you have nocaseglob enabled. You could check with `shopt -p|grep nocaseglob`. If enabled, the `[D]ebug` first matches your file named `debug` and then is passed as an argument to `grep`. That's why you should always use single quotes (and/or escape) with regex on the command prompt.

Comment: I clarified above what happens during the shell's filename expansion.

Comment: @forcefsck the `nocaseglob` is not relevant, the OP was grepping for `[Dd]` so it would match either case.

Comment: @JayAllen, yes, you are correct again.
Actually I use Linux and case-sensitive filesystem.
But auto-completion is case-insensitive.
Here is my test: in directory, which contains `debug` sub-directory, I issued following commands: `$ echo [D]ebug`, `$ echo [d]ebug`, `$ echo [i]ebug`. First 2 returned `debug`, the third one returned `[i]ebug`.

Comment: @terdon, `nocaseglob` **is** relevant here. Auto-completion is case-insensitive, because `nocaseglob` is enabled, as @forcefsck suggested.

Comment: @user1673789 I just realized you were talking about `[D]ebug`, I thought you were referring to `[Dd]ebug, sorry.